# Unhandled Exception inside OnException and inside catch block in Asp.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, unhandled-exception

I have a `GlobalExceptionFilterAttribute.cs` file that I intend to catch unhandled exceptions globally:

```
public override void OnException (HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext) 
{
     // SplunkHelper has bug that creates other exception
     SplunkerHelper.LogApplication(actionExecutedContext.Exception);
}
```

I have two questions:

1. How to take care the error raised by SplunkerHelper.LogApplication() to avoid crashing the server?
2. If there are some try catch blocks inside the application like below, would the exception caused by logger be caught in `GlobalExceptionFilterAttribute.cs`? If not, how to take care of it?

```
try
{
    // do something here
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    // logger is a null, which causes exception 
    logger.log("error")
    throw;
}
```

Comment: Please learn how to use Debug Diag to capture/analyze crash dumps and that’s going to get you started.

Comment: Thank you Lex Li for your advice! I will take a look at the crash dumps as well!